# Cloning an element multiple times with id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodes, clone

I have a li element parented to a ul with id holder. I need to clone the li multiple times, have all the clones parented to the holder ul and change their id. My hierarchy looks like this:

```
<ul id="holder">
<li>
 <label class="toggle-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
    <p class="neon" >MY1 </p>
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I clone the li element and than change it's id and MY1 so I get:

```
<ul id="holder">

<li>
 <label class="toggle-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
    <p class="neon" >MY: 1 </p>
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </label>
</li>

<li>
 <label class="toggle-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
    <p class="neon" >MY: 2 </p>
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </label>
</li>


<li>
 <label class="toggle-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
    <p class="neon" >MY: 3 </p>
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </label>
</li>

<li>
 <label class="toggle-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="4" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
    <p class="neon" >MY: 4 </p>
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </label>
</li>


</ul>
```

Comment: in javascript, there is a [clone node](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp) function. i think you can sort this out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cloneNode` to copy the `li` element and set the `deep` parameter to `true` to copy all the child nodes for that `li` element. Then use `querySelector` to target items within the clone and modify as required

```js
let ul=document.getElementById('holder');
let li=ul.querySelector('li:first-of-type');

for(let i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
  let id=i+2;
  
  let clone=li.cloneNode( true );
      clone.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').id=id;
      clone.querySelector('p').textContent=`MY: ${id}`;
      
  ul.appendChild( clone );
}
```

```html
<ul id="holder">
  <li>
    <label class="toggle-button">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>
      <p class="neon" >MY1 </p>
      <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```
let list = document.createElement("ul");
let numberOfListItems = 5; // set how many items in the list

function makeList(){

    let id = 1;

    for(i=0; i<=(numberOfListItems-1); i++){

        let listelement = document.createElement("li");
        let label = document.createElement("label");
        label.className = "toggle-button";
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
        input.id = id;
        input.onclick = "toggleCheckbox(this)"
        let par = document.createElement("p");
        par.className = "neon"
        par.innerText = "MY:" + id
        let i = document.createElement("i");
        i.className = "fa fa-power-off";

        listelement.appendChild(label);
        listelement.appendChild(input);
        listelement.appendChild(par);
        listelement.appendChild(i);
        list.appendChild(listelement)

        id+=1;
    }

}
```